# Java SIGSEV in libjvm.dylib with leiningen

Tags: java, macos, clojure

Running clojure's `lein` tool releases a nightmarish error in the JRE. What is odd is I can run a clojure console fine (something like `java -classpath ~/clojure-1.5.1/clojure-1.5.1.jar clojure.main`) so it seems specific to leiningen? Reinstalled the same version (which was working) but same issue.

The error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000010b39e740, pid=21632, tid=4875
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b12
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x44f740]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /programming/clojure/hermes/hs_err_pid21632.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
/usr/local/bin/lein: line 313: 21632 Abort trap: 6           "$LEIN_JAVA_CMD" -client "${BOOTCLASSPATH[@]}" $LEIN_JVM_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.easy=false -Dleiningen.original.pwd="$ORIGINAL_PWD" -Dleiningen.script="$SCRIPT" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" clojure.main -m leiningen.core.main "$@"
```

Then we have hundreds of lines (I can copy and paste anything from the log, but don't want to drop 500 lines here.)

About my machine (according to the log file)

```
---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Bsduname:Darwin 12.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 709, NOFILE 10240, AS infinity
load average:0.63 0.55 0.53

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 8352252k(2088063k free)

/proc/meminfo:


vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01) for bsd-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_21-b12), built on Apr  7 2013 14:55:50 by "java_re" with gcc 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

time: Sat May 11 00:44:48 2013
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: I suggest creating an issue at their issue tracker: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues

Comment: I definitely will if I can't find an answer in a day or so. Just want to rule out anything solvable in case it isn't related specifically to their project.